# How to define HTTP PUT method while performing a update operation using sapui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to perform the update operation , but im getting below error.

> HTTP request failed (400 Bad Request): {"error":{"code":"SY/530","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Inline component is not defined or not allowed (HTTP PUT)"},"innererror":{"transactionid":"50EFF5DC7C760020E005F672522CBC10","timestamp":"20201018162311.0364030","Error_Resolution":{"SAP_Transaction":"Run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP NW Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details","SAP_Note":"See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)","Batch_SAP_Note":"See SAP Note 1869434 for details about working with $batch.

```js
var oEntry1 = {};
oEntry1.Ebeln = Ebeln;
oEntry1.Bukrs = Bukrs;
oEntry1.Bsart = "EC";
oEntry1.Lifnr = Lifnr;
oEntry1.Ekorg = Ekorg;
oEntry1.Ekgrp = Ekgrp;
oEntry1.Waers = Waers; // set the item data to ProductSet
oEntry1.POItem = itemData;

oModel.update("/POHeaderSet('" + Ebeln + "')", oEntry1, {
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function(e) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to provide the detail error message at gateway.

Comment: is `itemData` a complex type (not a string, int, float, bool but an array/object)? This might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep insert is possible, but deep update is not possible as this is not supported.

To update parent and child in one Gateway call, you can use $batch feature.

Check the documentation for the batch feature: [OData v2 Batch Documentation](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/batch-processing/)